# php form doesn't submit

Tags: html, forms

This code doesn't submit form notwithstanding error log is empty, Please Tell me where my code is wrong

I want send email by SMTP

I use multi form in one page by accordion

I set SMTP in separate file

When I submit the form, absolutely nothing happens, why would that be? Here is my form code:

**HTML**:

```
<form class="text-center border border-light p-5" action="" method="POST">
<p class="title h4 mb-4">فرم ثبت درخواست نصب و راه اندازی</p>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row f1">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="نام / شرکت" value="<? $name ?>" >
                <p> <? $name_error ?> </p>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="پست الکترونیکی">
                <div class="radio2">
                    <h5>محل نصب</h5>
                    <input type="radio" name="place" id="rd1" value="اداری" checked><label for="rd1">اداری</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="place" value="تجاری" id="rd2"><label for="rd2">تجاری</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="place" value="مسکونی" id="rd3"><label for="rd3">مسکونی</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="place" value="صنعتی" id="rd4"><label for="rd4">صنعتی</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio2">
                    <h5>نوع دوربین</h5>
                    <input type="radio" name="cctvtype" value="آنالوگ" id="analog" ><label for="analog">آنالوگ</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="cctvtype" value="تحت شبکه" id="ip" checked><label for="ip">تحت شبکه</label>
                </div>
                <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="توضیحات اضافی"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" pattern="[0-9]+" placeholder="شماره تلفن / همراه"  value="<? $phone ?>">
                <p> <? $phone_error ?> </p>
                <select class="form-control slct" name="province" id="province" data-action="">
                    <option value="0">استان را انتخاب کنید</option> 
                    <option value="1">آذربایجان شرقی</option> 
                    <option value="2">آذربایجان غربی</option> 
                    <option value="3">اردبیل</option> 
                    <option value="4">اصفهان</option> 
                    <option value="5">البرز</option> 
                    <option value="6">ایلام</option> 
                    <option value="7">بوشهر</option> 
                    <option value="8">تهران</option> 
                    <option value="9">چهارمحال بختیاری</option> 
                    <option value="10">خراسان جنوبی</option> 
                    <option value="11">خراسان رضوی</option> 
                    <option value="12">خراسان شمالی</option> 
                    <option value="13">خوزستان</option> 
                    <option value="14">زنجان</option> 
                    <option value="15">سمنان</option> 
                    <option value="16">سیستان و بلوچستان</option> 
                    <option value="17">فارس</option> 
                    <option value="18">قزوین</option> 
                    <option value="19">قم</option> 
                    <option value="20">کردستان</option> 
                    <option value="21">کرمان</option> 
                    <option value="22">کرمانشاه</option> 
                    <option value="23">کهکیلویه و بویراحمد</option> 
                    <option value="24">گلستان</option> 
                    <option value="25">گیلان</option> 
                    <option value="26">لرستان</option> 
                    <option value="27">مازندران</option> 
                    <option value="28">مرکزی</option> 
                    <option value="29">هرمزگان</option> 
                    <option value="30">همدان</option> 
                    <option value="31">یزد</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="آدرس محل مورد نظر" required>
                <div class="tedadd col-lg-6">
                    <h5>تعداد دوربین </h5>
                    <input type="number" name="tedadd" id="">

                </div>
                <div class="tedadd col-lg-6">
                    <h5>ارتفاع نصب</h5>
                    <input type="number" name="ertefaenasb" id="">
                    <h5>( متر ) </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="tedadd col-lg-6">
                    <h5>متراژ کابل کشی</h5>
                    <input type="number" name="cable" id="">
                    <h5>( متر تقریبی ) </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="tedadd col-lg-6">
                    <h5>متراژ داکت</h5>
                    <input type="number" name="duct" id="">
                    <h5>( متر تقریبی ) </h5>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="addons" id="addons" placeholder="تعلقات اضافی / اختیاری">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 submit">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">ثبت درخواست</button>
                <span class=""><? $success ?></span>
                <pre><?php var_dump($_POST);?></pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and **PHP** code is:

```
include('smtp.php');
include('smtpserver.php');
$name = $email = $subject = $message = $phone = $ostan = $place =  "";
$cctvtype = $add = $numCctv = $heightCctv = $cable = $duct = $addons = $success = "";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if (empty($_POST["name"])){
        $name_error = "نام خود را بنویسید";
    }else{
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-z A-Z] *$/" ,$name));{
            $name_error = "نام خود را صحیح وارد نمایید";
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["phone"])){
        $phone_error = "شماره همراه و یا ثابت خود را وارد نمایید";
    }else{
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
        if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $id)) {
            $phone_error ="شماره همراه و یا ثابت خود را دقیق وارد نمایید";
        }
    }    
}


if($name_error == "" and $phone_error == ""){

    $userIp= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $subject = "نصب و راه اندازی  - $name"; 
    $message = $_POST['message']; 
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $ostan = $_POST['province'];
    $place = $_POST['place'];
    $cctvtype = $_POST['cctvtype'];
    $add = $_POST['address'];
    $numCctv = $_POST['tedadd'];
    $heightCctv = $_POST['ertefaenasb'];
    $cable = $_POST['cable'];
    $duct = $_POST['duct'];
    $addons = $_POST['addons'];

    $header = "From: $email\n". "Reply-To: $email\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
    $sub = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
    $email_to = "mrvahidazimi@gmail.com";
    $content = "آی پی مخاطب: $userIp\n"
        . "نام و نام خانوادگی: $name\n"
        . "پست الکترونیک: $email\n"
        . "موضوع پیام: $subject\n"
        . "شماره تلفن: $phone\n"
        . "استان: $ostan\n"
        . "آدرس: $add\n"
        . "نوع مکان: $place\n"
        . "نوع دوربین: $cctvtype\n"
        . "تعداد دوربین: $numCctv\n"
        . "ارتفاع نصب: $heightCctv . 'متر' \n"
        . "متراژ کابلکشی: $cable . 'متر' \n"
        . "متراژ داکت: $duct . 'متر' \n"
        . "متعلقات: $addons\n"
        . "متن پیام: $message\n";
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $email, $email_to, $sub, $content, $header);
        $SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
        $success = "درخواست شما با موفقیت ارسال شد بزودی با شما تماس خواهیم گرفت";
        $name = $email = $subject = $message = $phone = $ostan = $place = "";
        $cctvtype = $add = $numCctv = $heightCctv = $cable = $duct = $addons = "";
    }

} 
function test_input($data){
    $data = trim($datda);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: does your server have a SMTP service installed?

Comment: i bet error reporting is off and a muted error is being generated.

Comment: Yes it Does, I set information in smtp.php it is correct I know

Comment: <?php var_dump($_POST);?> shows all my data correct except submit string is 0 is it a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is empty, try setting the action value to the location of your SMTP script.

```
<form class='...' action='location/of/smtp.php' method='POST'>
...
</form>
```